# Swagger 2 on Spring boot - Can I put fullstop for required params displayed under an API?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have this api called `/predict`.

The required parameters can sometimes be `score1` and `score2` or

`info.score1` and `info.score2` depending on the dataset we get.

Right now how it looks like on my localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html is
[image]

Below is how I make it happen:

```
@ApiOperation(value="", response=RequestInput.class)
@RequestMapping(value="/predict", method= RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json", consumes="application/json")
    public ResponseEntity predict(Map<String, Object> inputs, @RequestBody RequestInput requestInput) {
    ...
}
```

`RequestInput.class` looks like this

```
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import lombok.Getter;

public class RequestInput {
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "", required = true)
    @Getter private Double score1;
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "", required = true)
    @Getter private Double score2;
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Isit possible to have

```
{
  "info.score1":0,
  "info.score2":0
}
```

2. How do I set the Example Value for the `Responses` part? Right now its reflecting what's on `requestInput`. I would like it to be

```
{
  "finalScore":0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question: ApiModelProperty has "name" which can be set to display your desired property name.
For second: check io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses and io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse. ApiResponse has an example property which also can be set.
About part of your question that states that your api can sometimes be one value and sometimes another: to be honest I do not think that this is possible to get in default swagger behavior.

Answer (score 0):

To handle dynamic attribute values in request, you can add setters `setInfoScore1` & `setInfoScore2` and mark them with `@JsonProperty`

```java
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import lombok.Getter;

public class RequestInput {
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "", required = true)
    @Getter private Double score1;
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "", required = true)
    @Getter private Double score2;

    @JsonProperty("info.score1")
    public void setInfoScore1(Double score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    @JsonProperty("info.score2")
    public void setInfoScore2(Double score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
}
```